# Summer/Winter clean up. What now?

Tags: discussion, cleanup

@kaiser has launched a brilliant clean up program, ♥ Summer clean up ♥, which I extented with the ♥ Winter clean up ♥, hahaha.

OK, these questions goes on hold, and eventually a few days later gets closed. My question is, what are going to happen with those questions

I know moderators and users with 10K+ reputation can decide to delete these questions completely after they are closed. Should we keep the one or two questions that is really good, or are we going to delete them all, like a proper clean out. Unfortunately my reputation is still to low to vote on these to completely delete them. My thought, 99% of all the questions in question are really non constructive, and should be deleted. No use keeping them as closed questions

Also, what is going to happen to the tags, like say [woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) and [plugin-contact-form-7](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-contact-form-7)? Are we just going to do the same with them as for the [plugin-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-recommendation) tag, edit them to say that these type of questions is off topic?

I would really like to hear what everybody, not just the moderators, have to add or say about this.

Answer (score 4):

On a technical note closed questions without positive activity are auto–deleted after a while, see [policies we have in place to remove old abandoned / dead questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: I think that link basically clears up everything. Really informational